# python itertools not printing multiples of 10

Tags: python, python-itertools

In my current python program which shows all possible combinations, it does not show the multiples of 10 (10,20,30,40,etc.) and I don't understand why, I am using the itertools library don't know if there is something that does this? I have looked online and I haven't found anything like it so maybe it has something to do with my installation of it? Anyway, here is the code.

```
import itertools
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import time
keyboard = Controller()
loop = True
a = 1
input("Welcome to the Password Possibilities Test")
input("This test will tell you how many possible")
input("combinations a password can have")
input("*all answers must start with an uppercase*")
num_length = 0
alpha_length = 0
sym_length = 0
num = input("So lets start does your password have numbers?\n")
alpha = input("Does it have letters?\n")
sym = input("Does it have symbols?\n")
long = input("Do you know how long the password is?\n")

possibilities = []

if long == "Yes":
    length = input("How long is the password?\n")
elif long == "No":
    print("Then we will go off of the average password length which is 8\n")
    length = 8

if num == "Yes":
    num_length = 10
    possibilities.append(0)
    possibilities.append(1)
    possibilities.append(2)
    possibilities.append(3)
    possibilities.append(4)
    possibilities.append(5)
    possibilities.append(6)
    possibilities.append(7)
    possibilities.append(8)
    possibilities.append(9)

else:
    num_length = 0

if alpha == "Yes":
    alpha_length = 52
    possibilities.append("a")
    possibilities.append("b")
    possibilities.append("c")
    possibilities.append("d")
    possibilities.append("e")
    possibilities.append("f")
    possibilities.append("g")
    possibilities.append("h")
    possibilities.append("i")
    possibilities.append("j")
    possibilities.append("k")
    possibilities.append("l")
    possibilities.append("m")
    possibilities.append("n")
    possibilities.append("o")
    possibilities.append("p")
    possibilities.append("q")
    possibilities.append("r")
    possibilities.append("s")
    possibilities.append("t")
    possibilities.append("u")
    possibilities.append("v")
    possibilities.append("w")
    possibilities.append("x")
    possibilities.append("y")
    possibilities.append("z")
    possibilities.append("A")
    possibilities.append("B")
    possibilities.append("C")
    possibilities.append("D")
    possibilities.append("E")
    possibilities.append("F")
    possibilities.append("G")
    possibilities.append("H")
    possibilities.append("I")
    possibilities.append("J")
    possibilities.append("K")
    possibilities.append("L")
    possibilities.append("M")
    possibilities.append("N")
    possibilities.append("O")
    possibilities.append("P")
    possibilities.append("Q")
    possibilities.append("R")
    possibilities.append("S")
    possibilities.append("T")
    possibilities.append("U")
    possibilities.append("V")
    possibilities.append("W")
    possibilities.append("X")
    possibilities.append("Y")
    possibilities.append("Z")
else:
    alpha_length = 0

if sym == "Yes":
    sym_length = 32
    possibilities.append("!")
    possibilities.append("@")
    possibilities.append("#")
    possibilities.append("$")
    possibilities.append("%")
    possibilities.append("^")
    possibilities.append("&")
    possibilities.append("*")
    possibilities.append("(")
    possibilities.append(")")
    possibilities.append("_")
    possibilities.append("+")
    possibilities.append("{")
    possibilities.append("}")
    possibilities.append("|")
    possibilities.append(":")
    possibilities.append("\\")
    possibilities.append("?")
    possibilities.append(">")
    possibilities.append("<")
    possibilities.append("~")
    possibilities.append("`")
    possibilities.append("[")
    possibilities.append("]")
    possibilities.append("\"")
    possibilities.append(";")
    possibilities.append("'")
    possibilities.append("/")
    possibilities.append(".")
    possibilities.append(",")
    possibilities.append("`")
else:
    sym_length = 0

num_length = int(num_length)
alpha_length = int(alpha_length)
sym_length = int(sym_length)
length = int(length)



calc = num_length + alpha_length + sym_length
final = pow(calc,length)
print("This password has ",final, "possibilities")
input("Click the ENTER key to view all of the combonations")
time.sleep(2)
for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(possibilities,length):
    print(*i, sep='')
print("This password has ",final, "possibilities")
exit = input("Would you like to exit?\n")
if exit == "Yes":
    pass
elif exit == "No":
    while loop == True:
        a = 1
```

Comment: Can you show example input/output and expected output?

Comment: So I tell the program that my password has numbers in it and is 4 characters long and it would print out 0001 to 9999 but it would skip all multiples of 10

Comment: Probably because combinations don't care about order. All the combinations involving 0  have 0 at the start of the number (because you've added 0 to `possibilities` first), then once 0 is used up, it won't appear again, which means multiples of 10 won't show up. I think you may want `permutations` instead, which takes order into consideration. Also, not that those massive `append` groups can be greatly shortened. The number one for example can be just `possibilities.extend(range(10))`.

Comment: Permutations does not work as it won't repeat any number

Comment: Combinations also don't repeat elements.

Answer (score 0):

When you would like to show all possible combinations you mean about the mathematical concept of the permutation with the repetitions. In python in the itertools library there is only permutations that it is like in mathematics the permutation without the repetitions. In python you can use in exchange for it the itertools.product. The full functioning code I enclose below:

```
import itertools
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()
loop = True
a = 1
input("Welcome to the Password Possibilities Test")
input("This test will tell you how many possible")
input("combinations a password can have")
input("*all answers must start with an uppercase*")
num_length = 0
alpha_length = 0
sym_length = 0
num = input("So lets start does your password have numbers?\n")
alpha = input("Does it have letters?\n")
sym = input("Does it have symbols?\n")
long = input("Do you know how long the password is?\n")

possibilities = []

if long == "Yes":
    length = input("How long is the password?\n")
elif long == "No":
    print("Then we will go off of the average password length which is 8\n")
    length = 8

if num == "Yes":
    num_length = 10
    possibilities.append("0")
    possibilities.append("1")
    possibilities.append("2")
    possibilities.append("3")
    possibilities.append("4")
    possibilities.append("5")
    possibilities.append("6")
    possibilities.append("7")
    possibilities.append("8")
    possibilities.append("9")

else:
    num_length = 0

if alpha == "Yes":
    alpha_length = 52
    possibilities.append("a")
    possibilities.append("b")
    possibilities.append("c")
    possibilities.append("d")
    possibilities.append("e")
    possibilities.append("f")
    possibilities.append("g")
    possibilities.append("h")
    possibilities.append("i")
    possibilities.append("j")
    possibilities.append("k")
    possibilities.append("l")
    possibilities.append("m")
    possibilities.append("n")
    possibilities.append("o")
    possibilities.append("p")
    possibilities.append("q")
    possibilities.append("r")
    possibilities.append("s")
    possibilities.append("t")
    possibilities.append("u")
    possibilities.append("v")
    possibilities.append("w")
    possibilities.append("x")
    possibilities.append("y")
    possibilities.append("z")
    possibilities.append("A")
    possibilities.append("B")
    possibilities.append("C")
    possibilities.append("D")
    possibilities.append("E")
    possibilities.append("F")
    possibilities.append("G")
    possibilities.append("H")
    possibilities.append("I")
    possibilities.append("J")
    possibilities.append("K")
    possibilities.append("L")
    possibilities.append("M")
    possibilities.append("N")
    possibilities.append("O")
    possibilities.append("P")
    possibilities.append("Q")
    possibilities.append("R")
    possibilities.append("S")
    possibilities.append("T")
    possibilities.append("U")
    possibilities.append("V")
    possibilities.append("W")
    possibilities.append("X")
    possibilities.append("Y")
    possibilities.append("Z")
else:
    alpha_length = 0

if sym == "Yes":
    sym_length = 32
    possibilities.append("!")
    possibilities.append("@")
    possibilities.append("#")
    possibilities.append("$")
    possibilities.append("%")
    possibilities.append("^")
    possibilities.append("&")
    possibilities.append("*")
    possibilities.append("(")
    possibilities.append(")")
    possibilities.append("_")
    possibilities.append("+")
    possibilities.append("{")
    possibilities.append("}")
    possibilities.append("|")
    possibilities.append(":")
    possibilities.append("\\")
    possibilities.append("?")
    possibilities.append(">")
    possibilities.append("<")
    possibilities.append("~")
    possibilities.append("`")
    possibilities.append("[")
    possibilities.append("]")
    possibilities.append("\"")
    possibilities.append(";")
    possibilities.append("'")
    possibilities.append("/")
    possibilities.append(".")
    possibilities.append(",")
    possibilities.append("`")
else:
    sym_length = 0

num_length = int(num_length)
alpha_length = int(alpha_length)
sym_length = int(sym_length)
length = int(length)



calc = num_length + alpha_length + sym_length
print(calc)
final = pow(calc,length)
print("This password has ",final, "possibilities")
input("Click the ENTER key to view all of the combonations")
time.sleep(2)
for i in itertools.product(possibilities, repeat = length):
    print(*i, sep='')
print("This password has ",final, "possibilities")
exit = input("Would you like to exit?\n")
if exit == "Yes":
    pass
elif exit == "No":
    while loop == True:
        a = 1
```